# Drupal pager won't work with "LIKE" in the query

Tags: sql, drupal, pager

I can't get this to work when using a query with `LIKE`. Example:

```
$sql = " SELECT DISTINCT u.uid, u.name, u.status, u.created, u.access FROM d_bi_test_2_shared.users u LEFT JOIN d_bi_test_2.users_roles ur ON u.uid = ur.uid WHERE u.uid != 0 AND LOWER(u.name) LIKE LOWER('%%er%%') ";
$sqlCount = " SELECT COUNT(*) FROM d_bi_test_2_shared.users u LEFT JOIN d_bi_test_2.users_roles ur ON u.uid = ur.uid WHERE u.uid != 0 AND LOWER(u.name) LIKE LOWER('%%er%%') ";
$count = 3;
$query = pager_query($sql, 5, 0, $sqlCount);
$output.=theme('pager', $count);
```

This gives me no pager at all. If I take out the `LIKE` it works, but I need to search like that for my form.

Comment: Did you run the query in MySQL itself, whithout going trough Drupal? When you did that, did the qeury return any results? It seems you misunderstand the %; you probably only want one %, like `(%er%)`.

Comment: Does it work if you remove the `DISTINCT`?

Answer (score 0):

try CONCAT('%%',LOWER(er),'%%')